# Assert Redis publication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, redis, publish-subscribe

I am writing a spec for an after_create callback. The spec looks like this:

```
it 'broadcasts creation' do
  message = Message.create(body: 'foo')
  expect(Redis.any_instance).to have_received(:publish)
end
```

My `Message` model looks like this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create -> { publish(:create) }

  private

  def publish(name)
    Redis.new.publish(
      self.class.inferred_channel_name,
      json(action)
    )

    Redis.new.publish(
      inferred_channel_name_for_single_record,
      json(action)
    )

    puts 'published!'
  end
end
```

I know that the callback runs because I am printing 'published' at the end, and I have verified that Redis indeed publishes something twice.

Nonetheless, my spec fails with the following message:

```
1) Message Methods #entangle without options broadcasts creation
 Failure/Error: expect(Redis.any_instance).to have_received(:publish)
   unstubbed, expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<AnyInstance:Redis>.publish(any_parameters)
 # ./spec/models/message_spec.rb:20:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am using [bourne](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourne) with mocha to use the `have_received` matcher.

How can I get this test to pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mock for `Redis` and stub out the class and instance methods — `new` and `publish`, respectively.

```
it "broadcasts creation" do
  redis = stub_redis

  Message.create(body: "foo")

  expect(redis).to have_received(:publish).twice
end

def stub_redis
  mock("redis").tap do |redis|
    redis.stubs(:publish)
    Redis.stubs(:new).returns(redis)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd note that there's a mock_redis gem that makes this work trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `expect_any_instance_of` mock.

```
it 'broadcasts creation' do
  expect(Redis.any_instance).to receive(:publish).twice
  message = Message.create(body: 'foo')
end
```

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance

Comment: It seems this doesn't actually allow me to use `have_received`, only `should_receive`... Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The code I posted is untested, so no, you're probably not doing anything wrong. Try the edited version that sets up the expectation first, and then runs the code to exercise it.